# Console Errors After Upgrading to Angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm-install

After running the below recommended commands to upgrade from Angular 2 to 4:

`npm install @angular/{common,compiler,compiler-cli,core,forms,http,platform-browser,platform-browser-dynamic,platform-server,router,animations}@latest typescript@latest --save`

... my app boots up, in that I get all green and a "webpack compiled successfully" message (see below):

```
** NG Live Development Server is running on http://localhost:4200 **
Hash: 323543f20rf93c6190621
Time: 47918ms
chunk    {0} main.bundle.js, main.bundle.js.map (main) 1.55 MB {3} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {1} polyfills.bundle.js, polyfills.bundle.js.map (polyfills) 239 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {2} styles.bundle.js, styles.bundle.js.map (styles) 87.4 kB {4} [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {3} vendor.bundle.js, vendor.bundle.js.map (vendor) 5.29 MB [initial] [rendered]
chunk    {4} inline.bundle.js, inline.bundle.js.map (inline) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]
webpack: Compiled successfully.
```

However, all that loads to the browser is a blank screen. And in the console I now see these errors:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'addEventListener' of undefined
>
> zone.js:522 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot set property 'addEventListener' of undefined ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: TypeError: Cannot set property 'addEventListener' of undefined

Note: I also completely removed my node-modules folder before running "npm install" again. After the update, my package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "cli-abc",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "build": "ng build",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^4.1.0",
    "@angular/common": "^4.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^4.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.1.0",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^2.0.0-beta.11",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^1.3.1",
    "@types/socket.io": "^1.4.29",
    "@types/socket.io-client": "^1.4.29",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "0.3.2",
    "angular2-chartjs": "0.2.0",
    "angular2-markdown": "^1.6.0",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.3.3",
    "ngx-perfect-scrollbar": "4.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "mydatepicker": "^1.10.1",
    "ngx-pagination": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.3.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.9"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.47",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.15",
    "codelyzer": "~3.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.1.0",
    "karma": "1.6.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.1.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.6.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.1",
    "ts-node": "3.0.2",
    "tslint": "^5.1.0",
    "typescript": "~2.3.2"
  }
}
```

I've also gone through and methodically updated any package.json dependencies that showed warnings around compatibility. So I have no more of those warnings when running "ng serve".

The added challenge here is that the console error messages are completely vague. All it tells me is that the error is *somewhere* between my `<app></app>` tags, which is to say, it could be *anywhere* in the app.

What's the likely issue here, and if it's not clear, how can I begin to narrow down the options?

Comment: Try removing all the components, just keep the main one for diagnostics.

Comment: it could be one of you third party libraries, make sure that all of them are latest versions supporting angular 4

Comment: Checked those. And now every dependency in my package.json is running its most current version. Still seeing same errors in the console.

Comment: what are you using to build the project , i would suggest use angular cli as it is quick and also you will not find these error i believe , install angular cli and using the cli build the project

Comment: Rahul, if you look at my code you'll realize this is an angular cli project.

Comment: I am not sure but try using '@next' instead of '@latest'